# Customized Authorization on Play framework using an external XACML-based authorization engine

Tags: java, playframework, authorization, xacml

I am developing my app using **Play 1.2.5** framework (Java) and for authorization I am using one of my company products which is a service oriented authorization engine for accessing any resource. It is based on **SOAP** services and is using **XACML** language.

My knowledge about Play is so limited and I just started using it!

I want to know is there any way to inject the user security information (access level) into the Play security module or I need to code it by some conditional statements inside the business logic myself?

Regards,

Comment: You need to look at the best interface you can use to implement a policy enforcement point. What XACML engine are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm thinking about DeadBolt module of Play! Actually our XACML authorization engine is an in-house product.

Comment: Did you ever get round to implementing a XACML PEP?